# Why are questions about insurance OT?

Tags: discussion, scope

Why are questions about insurance off topic and being closed as primarily opinion based ?
I think insurance is one of the most important things an expat would be concerned about and other expats would be one of the best sources of information.

Comment: Any chance you could link to a few examples?

Comment: Agreed - examples? I looked at the [health-insurance](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-insurance) tagged questions and all are currently open.

Comment: Of course just looking for insurance is probably considered shopping, or opinion based.  It's going to be different for every person, and rates/conditions change regularly.

Comment: However, questions about say, Aussie medicare covering you while working as an expat in India, would certainly be of interest, and objectively answerable.

Comment: Also, [Beware the slopes of “As an expat …”](http://meta.expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20/beware-the-slopes-of-as-an-expat)

Comment: Questions about insurance are definitely ***not*** off-topic. The two most popular questions are about health insurance, a few others about other types of insurance are still open (a few “close” votes but no consensus yet). So perhaps we need to discuss what makes an insurance question on- or off-topic, and not so much what we think about insurance in general.